# Unkonwn error occuring while testing iphone application

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am testing iphone application in xcode but it is giving unkonwo error

pplications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch
wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

i don't know why when view is loaded it breaks the application and gives this error

```
 My code where it breaks 

    - (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      if(!surveyList){
      surveyList=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
       }

      [self getSurveyList];

       }

      - (void)getSurveyList {

       NSString*user_id=user_id;
       NSLog(user_id);
      NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://celeritas-solutions.com/emrapp/surveyDescription.php?user_id=%@",user_id];


    NSArray *tempArray =[[DataManager staticVersion] startParsing:url];

   for (int i = 0; i<[tempArray count]; i++) {

    id *item = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSDictionary *dict = (NSDictionary *) item;
    ObjectData *theObject =[[ObjectData alloc] init];
    [theObject setSurvey_title:[dict objectForKey:@"survey_Title"]];
    [theObject setSurvey_Description:[dict objectForKey:@"survey_Description"]];    
    [theObject setDate_Created:[dict objectForKey:@"date_Created"]];




    [surveyList addObject:theObject];
    [theObject release];
    theObject=nil;




    int count =[surveyList count];
    NSLog(@"Total is %d",count);


    }
   }
```

Gives this error when calling this method from view did load method

Comment: could you be more specific? could you prove some code fragment? without this no one can tell what causes this error exactly...

Comment: holex when i click button to move to next screen it gives error in a method i am adding that

Comment: ...and you are 100% sure every outlet is connected correctly between the code and the `IB`, am I right? could you be _MORE_ specific, please?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the rootController in the AppDelegate

```
[self.window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
```

Use %i instead of %d

```
int count =[surveyList count];
NSLog(@"Total is %i",count);
```

Comment: this should resolve the "Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch" error. Are you testing on a Device or the Simulator?

Comment: on simulator first it was working fine when i move to next view on button click applicatoion gives this error

Comment: Set an Exception Breakpoint and look where it crashes. In Xcode press cmd+6 and click the + button in the lower right corner.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set following method in  AppDelegate.m file.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]]  autorelease];
// Override point for customization after application launch.
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
} else {
    self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
}
UINavigationController *navigation =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
 navigation.navigationBar.hidden=YES;
self.window.rootViewController = navigation;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```